# How to handle remove teams connector correctly?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a configured a Teams connector which the user wants to remove.
So i've registered an onRemoveHandler, to update by back-end data.

```
microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnRemoveHandler(function (removeEvent) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Remove',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            Id: "internalId",
        }),
        success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
            removeEvent.notifySuccess();
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            removeEvent.notifyFailure(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

This is working, but the problem is, that the onRemove handler is called directly after the user has pressed the remove button. This will trigger my back-end API which removes the connector configuration from the database. This would be fine, if not the user is asked for confirmation after that, and has the option to cancel the removal. The result is: in Teams, the connector is still configured, but my back-end has lost all information about the connector.

Is there a way to delay the remove callback until the user has confirmed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Connector removal flow. We are working on fixing this.